# Microsoft Access attempting to find table in macro as field

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am creating a database for my school which contains data for an event happening later on in the year. They need a query that displays the events and how many people are going. At the same time they want me to display an error if the venue is overbooked.

I attempted to do this via a macro. The macro would open the attendence_rpt report, then run the macro to see whether the venue is overbooked, like so:

```
'------------------------------------------------------------
' Macro1
'
'------------------------------------------------------------
Function Macro1()
On Error GoTo Macro1_Err

    DoCmd.OpenReport "attendence_rpt", acViewReport, "", "", acNormal
    If (Reports!attendence_rpt!CountOfAttendeeID > Reports!attendence_rpt!venue_tbl!Capacity) Then
        Beep
        MsgBox "test", vbOKOnly, "test"
    End If


Macro1_Exit:
    Exit Function

Macro1_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Macro1_Exit

End Function
```

When I run the macro however, it comes up with this error:

```
Microsoft Access can't find the field 'venue_tbl' referred to in your expression
```

This means that the macro is trying to find the linked table 'venue_tbl' as a field.

Is there any way to fix this? Or is there an easier method to achieve the same goal?

Below are some photos of the database in Access:

[image: Query Relationship]

[image: Query Data]

[image: Macro In Access]

Comment: You first show VBA code then an image of macro. I recommend eliminating the macro and just using VBA. Why are you including table name in reference path? Should not be needed unless there are multiple Capacity fields from different tables in the query. If you do use table prefix, then use a dot between it and field name as shown in query.

Comment: Side note: "attendence" is a misspelling of "attendance".

Comment: Before Access 2000, Access did expose data fields as report fields. If you want to do that now, you need to declare an named object on the report, and link it to the data.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new field to the report that contains *venue_tbl!Capacity* and make it *not visible* (unless you want to show the new field to the user). Then change the line in your macro:

```vb
If (Reports!attendence_rpt!CountOfAttendeeID > Reports!attendence_rpt!venue_tbl!Capacity) Then
```

to:

```vb
If Reports!attendence_rpt!CountOfAttendeeID > Reports!attendence_rpt!NameOfNewField Then
```

where *NameOfNewField* is the name of the field you added.

Answer (score 0):

You must not reference the table in the report.

So this is WRONG:

```
Reports!attendence_rpt!venue_tbl!Capacity
```

And this is CORRECT:

```
Reports!attendence_rpt!Capacity
```